# Por donde empezar para relaciones Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Buenas a todos, soy nuevo en Swift, llevo 3 semanas aprendiendo por mi cuenta y estoy desarrollando una app muy sencillita para guardar la ropa

De momento he logrado que el usuario meta en un Data Core la ropa con su foto, marca y nombre, se muestre en un Cell View, se pueda editar, borrar y añadir, etc...

Ahora, en la segunda parte de la aplicación, la idea es que el usuario pueda crear "conjuntos" con esa ropa, es decir, que si yo he metido en el anterior "Entity" del Data Core los datos de la ropa que utilizo, ahora pueda utilizar varios de esos elementos para crear nuevos conjuntos y que estén relacionados de tal manera que al borrar, por ejemplo, unos zapatos, estos desaparezcan de los conjuntos

De momento estoy indagando como puedo hacer una nueva Entity que como valores los de la anterior Entity y solo he encontrado algo de relaciones one-to-one, one-to-multiple, etc.. pero no se si debo usar alguna librería para simplificar, buscar algún tutorial que desarrolle un problema parecido al mío, etc...

Cualquier ayuda la agradecería un montón

Muchísimas gracias por todo

Un saludo

Comment: Hola @FlashHardcore, Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero responder bien a tu pregunta.

Primero aclarar que es un ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te explico:

Yo lo he planteado que todos los objetos tienen **atributos en común**. Por eso yo he creado un **objeto padre** llamado **Ropa** que tiene los atributos en común de los objetos como son **color, material y tallaje**.

Luego he creado los objetos por ejemplo **camiseta, pantalón y zapatos**. Cada uno de ellos puede llevar sus propios atributos que no los posea ningún otro objeto, en esto consiste la **orientación a objetos**.

Luego he creado el objeto **Conjunto** que no es más que un objeto sin atributos, solo posee **relaciones 1-1** con los distintos objetos posibles como son **zapato, camisetas y pantalones**.

Quedaría algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo que le pongas **relaciones inversas** ya que sino te saltan warnings muy molestos, cosa que soponía que XCode 9 iba a solucionar pero no...

Ahora te voy a intentar explicar como se hace un objeto padre y las relaciones en XCode 9. Creo que será suficiente con palabras, en caso de no ser así dímelo y adjunto fotos.

**Objeto padre:** Creas un objeto en el DataModel que tenga los atributos en común entre varios objetos (**Ropa**).
Luego creas los objetos (por ejemplo **Zapato**) y te vas al menú lateral derecho y entre las diferentes opciones hay una que dice: **Parent Entity**.

Ahí seleccionas **Ropa** como objeto padre. Y así con todos los objetos que quieras que tengan como padre a **Ropa**.

En tema de relaciones... bueno, crearlas ya sabes, para hacer que una relación sea inversa solo tienes que ir al objeto de la relación y crear una relación hacia el objeto anterior. Me explico con un ejemplo:

Conjunto tiene una relación con **Zapato**.

Para volver esta relación inversa solo tienes que crear una relación **Zapato** con **Conjunto** y donde dice inverse seleccionar la relación previa.

***Espero haberte ayudado!***

PD: Como aportación personal, podrías probar [Realm](https://realm.io)

Comment: Muchas gracias,he estado mirando un poco y efectivamente si debo profundizar en las relaciones.

La idea principal era hacer algo más simple y a medida que vaya ganando conocimientos ir haciendo más compleja la App.

De moment solo quiero que el usuario registre ropa con Foto, Marca y Nombre y que luego pueda registrar un Conjunto o Look con foto, estilo y conjunto de ropa que lo conforman.

En cualquier caso, muchísimas gracias por todo y un cordial saludo!

Comment: @FlashHardcore Mira normalmente en core data se hace una entidad separada para las imágenes. Esto se hace por que las imágenes pueden ocupar demasiado y los registros de CoreData tienen un limite máximo de memoria. Entonces hace una entidad a parte que se llame image con un atributo image que guarde binary data y en el menu de la derecha marcas la casilla "Allows External Storage" para que en caso que sea muy grande use la memoria del disco y no la de core data